# Read google book in android

Tags: java, android, google-data-api

i have developed an application in which i fetch books using googleapibook search. I have an isbn no. Now i want to let my user read that book page by page. But i didn't find any method or solution to read book in java or android.

Here is my code.

```
package com.project.bookhunt;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BookSearchParser 
{
    Context m_context;
    static ArrayList<Book_Item> books= new ArrayList<Book_Item>();
    String searchResult;
    BookSearchParser(Context c,URL url)
    {
        try
        {

           m_context=c;
           HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

           GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(url.toString());
           int statusCode = client.executeMethod(getMethod);
           System.out.println("status Code"+statusCode);
           System.out.println(getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString());
           searchResult=getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
           parseJSON(searchResult);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Book_Item> getBooks()
    {
        return books;
    }

    private void parseJSON(String object)
     {
         try
         {
         books=new ArrayList<Book_Item>();
         JSONObject jSonObject = new JSONObject(object);
         if(jSonObject.getInt("totalItems")>0)
         {
             JSONArray jSonObjectArray = jSonObject.getJSONArray("items");
             for(int count = 0; count < jSonObjectArray.length();count++)
             {  
                    Book_Item item=new Book_Item();
                    JSONObject jsonItem = (JSONObject) jSonObjectArray.get(count);

                    if(jsonItem.has(("id")))
                    {
                        item.setId(jsonItem.getString("id"));   
                    }
//                  else
//                  {
//                      item.setId("No Id");
//                  }


                    if(jsonItem.has("selfLink"))
                    {
                      item.setSelfLink(jsonItem.getString("selfLink"));

                    }
//                  else
//                  {
//                      item.setSelfLink("No Link Avilable");
//                  }



                        if(jsonItem.has("volumeInfo"))
                        {
                             JSONObject volumeInfo = (JSONObject)jsonItem.get("volumeInfo");

                                if(volumeInfo.has("title"))
                                {
                                    item.setTitle(volumeInfo.getString("title"));
                                }
//                              else
//                              {
//                                  item.setTitle("No Title");
//                              }


                                if(volumeInfo.has("subtitle"))
                                {
                                    item.setSubTitle(volumeInfo.getString("subtitle"));
                                }
//                              else
//                              {
//                                  item.setSubTitle("No SubTitle Avilable");
//                              }
//                              
                                    if(volumeInfo.has("authors"))
                                    {
                                         JSONArray Authors = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
                                            for(int authorCount=0;authorCount<Authors.length();authorCount++)
                                            {
                                                    item.setAuthor(Authors.getString(authorCount));         
                                            }
                                    }



                                  if(volumeInfo.has("description"))
                                  {
                                      item.setDiscription(volumeInfo.getString("description"));
                                  }
//                                else
//                                {
//                                    item.setDiscription("No Description Avilable");
//                                }

                                  if(volumeInfo.has("averageRating"))
                                  {
                                      item.setRating(volumeInfo.getString("averageRating"));
                                  }


                                  if(volumeInfo.has("industryIdentifiers"))
                                  { 
                                      JSONArray isbnArray = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("industryIdentifiers");


                                            for(int isbnCount=0;isbnCount<isbnArray.length();isbnCount++)
                                            {
                                                JSONObject isbn=(JSONObject)isbnArray.get(isbnCount);
                                                if(isbn.getString(("type")).equals("ISBN_10"))
                                                {
                                                    item.setIsbn10(isbn.getString("identifier"));
                                                }
                                                if(isbn.getString(("type")).equals("ISBN_13"))
                                                {
                                                    item.setIsbn13(isbn.getString("identifier"));
                                                }

                                            }

                                  }

                                if(volumeInfo.has("categories"))
                                {
                                      JSONArray categoriesArray = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("categories");

                                        for(int j=0;j<categoriesArray.length();j++)
                                        {
                                            item.setCategory(categoriesArray.getString(j));                 
                                        }
                                }
//                              else
//                              {
//                                  item.setCategory("No category");
//                              }
//                              


                                if(volumeInfo.has("imageLinks"))
                                {
                                    JSONObject ImageLinks = volumeInfo.getJSONObject("imageLinks");

                                    if(ImageLinks.has("smallThumbnail"))
                                    {
                                        item.setSmallThumb(ImageLinks.getString("smallThumbnail"));
                                    }
                                    if(ImageLinks.has("thumbnail"))
                                    {
                                        item.setThumb(ImageLinks.getString("thumbnail"));
                                    }
//                                  else
//                                  {
//                                      //item.setSmallThumb("No Thumbnail");
//                                  }
//                                  
                                    if(ImageLinks.has("previewLink"))
                                    {
                                        item.setPreviewLink((ImageLinks.getString("previewLink")));
                                    }
//                                  else
//                                  {
//                                      item.setPreviewLink("No Thumbnail");
//                                  }



                                }
//                              else
//                              {
//                                  //item.setSmallThumb("No Thumbnail");
//                                  item.setPreviewLink("No Preview");
//                              }
                        }


                        books.add(item);//add one volume to array_list
              }
         }
         else
         {
             Toast.makeText(m_context, "0 Record Found..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }











         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is just for getting knowledge, because there is a official app of Google Books

Comment: i know buddy..but how can i view or read google book...do u have any idea??

Comment: Maibe if you use a webview and the Embedded Viewer API, possibly you will be able to get previews of the book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here with a possible solution.

As you are using the Book Search API and you are able to get the ISBN of the book

Then, to allow your user to read the book , maybe:

Using a WebView with the Google Docs Embedded Viewer API + your ISBN you will be able to load the book preview inside that WebView

for example, a WebView with this code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Books Embedded Viewer API Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("books", "0");

      function initialize() {
        var viewer = new google.books.DefaultViewer(document.getElementById('viewerCanvas'));
        viewer.load('**ISBN:0738531367**');
      }

      google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="viewerCanvas" style="width: 600px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my solution for you, the trick is located at : google.books.DefaultViewer(document.getElementById('viewerCanvas'));
            viewer.load('**ISBN:0738531367**');

I hope this helps you

for a better understanding on this please visit http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/viewer/developers_guide.html at **The "Hello, World" of the Embedded Viewer API**

When you use that API you can get something like this: http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/viewer/examples/book-simple.html

Comment: Hi Nirav, are you able to solve your problem? I am also looking for some sample code on how to read google books in android app. Please if you got the solution provide some sample code or share your idea. Thank you.